# StackPanel loaded is not getting fired in.cs page

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Loaded ="SPImage_Loaded" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" >
                            <Button x:Name="myButton"   
                        Click="Btn_Click">
                            <Image  x:Name="imgMarks" " Stretch="None"/>
                        </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

in .cs  i have   defined the event for stack panel

```
 private void SPImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var TargetMarks = sender as StackPanel;
            Image imgMarks= (Image)TargetScore.FindName("imgMarks");

             Marks obj = (Marks )TargetMarks.DataContext;

// here marks oject  would be  containg the  details
// here if marks.score object value  is  1 then bind the image
//else
// dnt bind the image . that is  logic i am trying to  do.

            imgMarks.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/a1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Is there any better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Can you include more of your XAML file?  Without more than just the DataTemplate there is not much we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full xaml and .cs file, are you certain the x:Class for the user control specified in the xaml is the same as the class name in your .cs file?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Converter for similar things to this. Bind the Source of your image to your Marks object then decide what the Source is based on the score.

Hope it helps

[Tim Heur article on Converters and DataBinding](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)